# Reading @Transient fields from database

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a spring boot application with database and entity with @Transcient field... here you have a sample code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "dogs")
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
@ApiModel
public class Dog {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    
    @Transient
    public Boolean happy;
}

Dog dog1 = dogsRepository.findById(1);
dog1.setHappy(true);

Dog dog2 = dogsRepository.findById(1);
System.out.println("dog2 is happy = " + dog2.isHappy());
```

and the last line prints `dog2 is happy = true` on the screen. How it is possible? @Transient fields are not persisting in a database.

Comment: It isn't retrieving from the db but from the first  level cache.

Comment: JPA first level cache?

Answer (score 0):

The method `dogsRepository.findById` checks the 1st level cache. If it cannot be found there it will be fetched from the database and stored in the 1st level cache. That is why the 2nd call to `findById` will not retrieve it from the database but from the cache instead. That is why dog1 and dog2 are the same object in your case.

That will not happen for example if you clear the cache between the `findById` calls or execute the calls in different transactions.